# Throughput test setup with two local Ethernet interfaces

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I'm currently testing the routing performance of a hardware device (DUT - Device Under Test) with the following setup (all addresses start with `192.168.`):

```
eth0 (29.2) <---> eth1 (29.1)  eth2 (30.1) <---> eth0 (30.2)
HOST1             |~~~~~~~~~DUT~~~~~~~~~~|       HOST2
```

`Iperf` is working just fine in this setup.

However, I want to get rid of HOST2, since another Ethernet card is available on HOST1. This is what I want to achieve:

```
eth0 (29.2) <---> eth1 (29.1)  eth2 (30.1) <---> eth1 (30.2)
HOST1             |~~~~~~~~~DUT~~~~~~~~~~|       HOST1
```

How can I configure the Linux routing on HOST1 such that the packets from eth0 to eth1 would go through the DUT and not internally though the kernel?

I'm running Debian with a 3.0 kernel. The iproute2 version is `ss110629`.

Comment: maybe this will help : http://serverfault.com/questions/127636/force-local-ip-traffic-to-an-external-interface

Answer (score 1):

Routing combined with snat/dnat should do the trick.  The basic idea here is to assign each device on HOST1 a second, "virtual" ip address in a second subnet.  The virtual addresses are translated into the actual ones just before/after they leave/enter host1.
Use the following setup and direct iperf traffic at 192.168.9.2 or 192.168.10.2 (depending on desired direction of the flow)

#### IP address assignment

HOST1

- eth0 192.168.29.2/24 (the "virtual" address for this device will be 192.168.9.2)
- eth1 192.168.30.2/24 (the "virtual" address for this device will be 192.168.10.2)

DUT

- eth1 192.168.29.2/24
- eth2 192.168.30.2/24

#### Static routes

HOST1

- 192.168.10.2/24 via 192.168.29.1
- 192.168.9.2/24 via 192.168.30.1

DUT

- 192.168.9.2/24 via 192.168.29.2
- 192.168.10.3/24 via 192.168.30.2

#### iptables rules on HOST1

POSTROUTING

- SNAT packets destined for 192.168.9.2 to 192.168.10.2
- SNAT packets destined for 192.168.10.2 to 192.168.9.2

PREROUTING

- DNAT packets destined for 192.168.9.2 to 192.168.29.2
- DNAT packets destined for 192.168.10.2 to 192.168.30.2